# How can I fix this issue about “Java Version” in my Java Applet Project?

Tags: java, applet

I have a Java Applet Project.

I have a problem about my Java version. I've tried a lot of way for fix this problem but i can't. And my Java version updated. I will sign my code but first i must fix this problem.

When I've entered and click to run, this is first message;

[image: first message]

I click 'don't block' and;

[image: don't block]

I click 'OK' and;

[image: ok]

I click 'Details' and;

[image: details]

And if you want to see this problem, you can enter my website to see applet;
http://www.armabilgisayar.net/demoebys

How can I fix this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: You should reformat the question using the <img> tags so we don't have to visit some unknown site to see the screenshots.

Comment: @BiyanAliGümüşoğlu even if you can't add images, please atleast post valid URL's

Comment: Your applet code contains some malformed coding which poses serious security threats as identified by Java!

Comment: Unsigned and self-signed applets are blocked by default. See https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml It also describes a workaround.

Comment: If i sign all jar files, it will be fix?